# Return sum of attribute A of nodes with the same attribute B in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, match, cypher

I'm new to Cypher and I was wondering how to do this. This is the situation:

I have a database with a few airports in it. Every airport has a city and a capacity. Now I want to match all airports in the same city (so they have the same value for the city attribute) and display the sum of the capacity attribute of the airports in the same city. I'd like to return the different cities and the total capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypher's got you covered ;)

```
MATCH (airport:Airport)
RETURN airport.city AS city, sum(airport.capacity) AS total_capacity
ORDER BY city
```

OR

```
ORDER BY total_capacity
```